# How can I set up a multiprocessing.Pipe to a nested subprocess?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have an executable that wraps a python script, perhaps as simple as the following:

```sh
# my_child_wrapper.sh
echo About to start the child
python my_child.py "$@"
echo Child finished
```

Because of this wrapping layer, I can't use the obvious APIs in `multiprocessing.Process`.

I'd like to set up a multiprocessing `Pipe` between the child and the parent. The naive approach below does not work, because the objects returned by `Pipe` are not pickleable:

```
# my_parent.py
import multiprocessing

a, b = multiprocessing.Pipe()
def run_child():
    subprocess.check_call(['my_child_wrapper.sh', pickle.dumps(b)])
Thread(target=run_child).start()
a.send('Some python object')
```

```
# my_child.py
import sys
import pickle

b = pickle.loads(sys.argv[1])
while True:
    print(b.recv())
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use the shell wrapper code? If you can explicitly call the python code in `my_child.py` in `my_parent.py` then it should be easier (i.e. 
basically just the pipes [example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#exchanging-objects-between-processes)).

Assuming you can't do that, it's possible to create a named pipe in a similar way but more explicitly using `mkfifo` and just passing the name of the pipe.

I had to add a shebang line on your `.sh` but otherwise here is an example:

```
# my_parent.py
from threading import Thread
import os
import subprocess

pipename = 'mypipe'
try:
    os.mkfifo(pipename)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

# start child
def run_child():
    subprocess.check_call(['/MYPATH/my_child_wrapper.sh', pipename])
Thread(target=run_child).start()

# send data
with open(pipename, 'wb') as p:
    p.write(b'Something')
```

And then the child code:

```
# my_child.py
import os
import sys

pipename = sys.argv[1]
while True:
    with open(pipename, 'rb') as p:
    print(p.read())
```

It's an OS piped version of what you asked about so hopefully that's interesting but not a straightforward solution to what you asked about doing.

Comment: Yes, the premise of this question is there exists some wrapper. For simplicity, I've shown a shell wrapper here, but in reality I'm dealing with a C++ wrapper, which embeds a python interpreter

Comment: Regarding `p.write(b'Something')` - in my example, I send arbitrary python objects, but in your example only byte arrays can be sent.